# How can I create arrays of suitable candidates based on certain criteria?

Tags: php

So to brief you on the question:

- I have a number of employees field in a form.
- Employees have a salary and the day rate is calculated using (salary / 260)

  - Assuming employees work a fixed standard day
- A task has a certain budget and a date range (start to end - e.g. 29/03/2017 to 31/03/2017)
- A task **also** requires a fixed amount of employees (i.e. 3)

Now with those details in mind, I want to get a list of **x** employees (the fixed amount, i.e. 3) for which those employee's salaries match the date range of the project, and also slot into the budget.

I started doing this as follows, but have no idea how to continue further:

```
$employees = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'salary' => 22000
    );
);
$startDate = some_date_here;
$endDate = some_date_here;

foreach($employees as &$user) {
    $dayRate = round($user['salary'] / 260, 2);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php#117691, I managed to find the days between the dates of a project as follows (code update):

```
function days_diff($d1, $d2) {
    $x1 = days($d1);
    $x2 = days($d2);
        if ($x1 && $x2) {
        return abs($x1 - $x2);
    }
}

function days($x) {
    if (get_class($x) != 'DateTime') {
        return false;
    }
        $y = $x->format('Y') - 1;
    $days = $y * 365;
    $z = (int)($y / 4);
    $days += $z;
    $z = (int)($y / 100);
    $days -= $z;
    $z = (int)($y / 400);
    $days += $z;
    $days += $x->format('z');
        return $days;
}

$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $startDate);
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $endDate);
$projectDays = days_diff($startDate, $endDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by the following code.

```
            $startDate = some_date_here;
            $endDate = some_date_here;
            $noOfDays = calculate_using_end-start;

            $employeeRate = [];
            $noOfEmployeesRequired = 3;

            foreach($employees as $index=>$user) {
                $dayRate = round($user['salary'] / 260, 2);
                $totalRate = $dayRate*$noOfDays;
                $employeeRate[$user['id']] = $totalRate;
            }
```

Now I have all employees Cost hence i sort it and find the cheapest solution

```
            sort($employeeRate);
            $output = array();
            $counter = 0;

            foreach($employeeRate as $id=>$emp) {
                array_push($output, $id);
                $counter++;
                if($counter == $noOfEmployeesRequired) {
                    break;
                }
            }
```